# insert into bulk data into the oracle tables with self join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have a table called `p_relations` which has 4 columns `employeename`, `access`, `manager_name`, `comments` and i can get these details from the table `p_employees` which has `emp_id`, `name`, `manager_id` .

For example in `p_employees` table i have this data:

```
1001  kiran  2001
2001  rahul  3001
```

now in `p_relations` table i have to insert the data like this

```
kiran  1   rahul
```

actually we have to insert bulk data . could you please sugget me the procedure or query for this.

i developed simple procedure but it doesnt work:

```
    DECLARE
    e_name VARCHAR2(20);
    m_name VARCHAR2(20);
    manager_id VARCHAR2(20);
     CURSOR c_lecturer IS
       SELECT name,manager_id FROM p_employees;
   BEGIN
      OPEN c_lecturer;
     LOOP
     FETCH c_lecturer INTO e_name, manager_id;
         SELECT name INTO manager_name FROM WKS_CONT.SIBER_EMPLOYEES WHERE emp_id=manager_id;

          INSERT INTO p_relations  VALUES(e_name, ,1,manager_name);

    EXIT WHEN c_lecturer%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_lecturer;
 END;
```

Please help me on this

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Does it not compile, does it execute but not do what you expected? Any error messages you can provide?

Comment: `e_name VARCHAR2(20)` : names length can't be more than 20?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could use a hierarchical query, which uses the `CONNECT BY PRIOR` syntax, and instead of a PL/SQL loop just use a simple `INSERT INTO SELECT...`:

```
    INSERT INTO p_relations
    SELECT name, 1, (SELECT name FROM p_employees m WHERE e.manager_id = m.emp_id)
    FROM p_employees e
    START WITH manager_id IS NULL -- Specify how to identify your top manager, the big boss.
    CONNECT BY emp_id = PRIOR manager_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

probably not all empoyees have a manager. 
YOu can do it with a left join:

```
INSERT into p_relations
SELECT a.name, 1, b.name as manager_name 
FROM WKS_CONT.SIBER_EMPLOYEES a
    left join WKS_CONT.SIBER_EMPLOYEES b on (b.emp_id=a.manager_id);
```

your procedure can be improved in this way:

```
DECLARE
e_name VARCHAR2(20);
m_name VARCHAR2(20);
manager_id VARCHAR2(20);
 CURSOR c_lecturer IS
   SELECT name,manager_id FROM p_employees;
BEGIN 
   OPEN c_lecturer; 
   LOOP 
       FETCH c_lecturer 
       INTO e_name, manager_id; 

       BEGIN
         SELECT name INTO manager_name 
         FROM WKS_CONT.SIBER_EMPLOYEES WHERE emp_id=manager_id;
       EXCEPTION when no_rows_found then manager_name:=null;
       END;

       INSERT INTO p_relations  VALUES(e_name, 1, manager_name);

EXIT WHEN c_lecturer%NOTFOUND;
 END LOOP;
CLOSE c_lecturer;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible it's normally more efficient to use [`bulk collect`](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html). It looks slightly scarier but it's well worth the effort to understand; for a start it does less DML

```
declare

   cursor c_lecturer is
    select e.name, 1, m.name
      from p_employees e
      left outer join wks_cont.siber_employees m
        on e.emp_id = m.manager_id
           ;

   t__lecturer is table of c_lecturer%rowtype index by binary_integer;
   t_lecturer t__lecturer;

begin

   open c_lecturer;
   loop

      fetch c_lecturer bulk collect 
       into t_lecturer limit 1000;

      exit when t_lecturer.count = 0;

      forall i in t_lecturer.first .. t_lecturer.last loop
         insert into p_relations(e_name, access, manager_name)
         values t_lecturer(i)
                ;

      commit;

   end loop;
   close c_lecturer;

end;
/
```

Of course yet more efficient is a simple insert:

```
insert into p_relations(e_name, access, manager_name)
select e.name, 1, m.name
  from p_employees e
  left outer join wks_cont.siber_employees m
    on e.emp_id = m.manager_id
       ;
```